# Saving ImageView background state

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview, onsaveinstancestate

I have an ImageView `ImageView1`, whose background can be set by the user. How can I save the state of that background, so that when the user closes the app and reopens it, the background of `ImageView1` is still the same?

Is it possible with `onSaveInstanceState` or do I have to write something different, and if so: How can I do this?

Right now I have:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("ImageView1", imageView1);
```

but `imageView1` gets red underline, even though declared before to id of ImageView

Comment: What is the type of the background that the user is setting? Other Image or Color? If it’s not image, you could save them in sharedpreferences.

Comment: it's a png from @drawable

Comment: so its an drawable reference, so you can definitely use onSaveInstanceState() as it’d be in the Integer reference (R.drawable.selected_drawable)

Comment: but if I use outstate.putInt("Image1", imageView1); "imageView1" gets red underline

Comment: Check this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-do-i-get-the-resource-id-of-an-image-if-i-know-its-name-in-android

Comment: how is that supposed to help me? I know how to get id from image. "imageView1" is already id of my Image, but still gets red underline...

Comment: then pl. add relevant code and error

Comment: You are adding ImageView which not an Integer (Id), its a View. Pl. refer the above link.

Comment: haha never mind i get it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shared preferences:

- Save to shared preferences on change.
- Get from shared preferences on app reopen.

Check documentation for more:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Answer (score 0):

You can use  SharedPreferences as follows:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
 sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("data", 0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
 editor.putString("image", //put image path here);
 editor.apply();
```

Then override the onResume method as follows

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("data", 0);
String imagePath = sharedPreferences.getString("image", ""); //default value is empty
}
```

Then load image using picasso or glide like..

```
 Picasso.get().load(imagePath).into(imageview);
```